# Ventilation shafts in the Great Pyramid

Tags: air, gas

In the Great Pyramid of Giza, there are four channels, apparently going all the way from inner chambers to the exterior of the pyramid. Archaeologists have speculated that these are ventilation shafts used to deliver air either to workers to the inner chambers after the pyramid was completed.

What would be the necessity and usefulness of such shafts for air delivery purposes? Would a person in the inner chambers suffocate without them? How effective would long shafts like that be in ventilating the chambers?

Comment: The question if people in closed spaces suffocate is obviously a trivial medical question, but  it certainly doesn't belong into physics. The details of the construction of pyramids is civil engineering.

Comment: The only remotely physics related aspect to this are the searches by Alverez 50 years ago for hidden passages and chambers using muon detectors. Nothing showed up.

Comment: Great question. I've often wondered myself how effective they'd be for ventilation. They seem too long and narrow for outside, desert breezes to overcome the frictional forces inherent in long, narrow pipes. I just don't think they'd meet OSHA standards for ventilation.

Comment: @Inquisitive That's what I was thinking, they seem so long and skinny compared to normal air ducts, but I don't know how to compute the physics of the situation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is diffusion. Oxygen cannot diffuse in, and carbon dioxide cannot diffuse out, of a long tunnel. Add a shaft, and you can create a draft. Now you have convection - much more effective means of delivering sufficient oxygen to the interior.

Interestingly, in some situations (old mines, like the one found on Oak Island), a pair of shafts were built. A fire lit under one shaft would cause air flow up the "chimney" and draw fresh air in through the other shaft. Inventive solution in the days before fans.

Comment: The prairie-dog burrow effect would almost certainly be sufficient for the pyramid. Winds high on the faces (which are faster than those near the ground) of the pyramids would generate enough  Bernoulli pressure drop to get a little draw. It takers surprising low flow rates.

Comment: I understand the basic idea of creating a draft, but given the length and sizes of the shafts would it actually work?

Comment: In the case of a chimney and a small fire, longer is actually better. You just need a tiny airflow to replenish the oxygen - a single human might need 500 liters per hour. In a shaft that is 20x20 cm across, that requires an air velocity of less than 4 mm per second. Pretty sure the Bernoulli effect alone would be sufficient even with very little wind.

Comment: Incidentally [this article](http://www.catchpenny.org/shafts.html) casts some doubt on the need for these shafts for ventilation. Not all pyramids seem to have them (or perhaps they were just better filled as construction was completed).